# Reading barcodes & sending information to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, barcode-scanner

I have an application to be used in a shop, where the employee needs to read the barcode of an item and have its details showing up on screen. The application is to be built in ASP.NET.

Is this doable? Do I need 3rd party libraries. Can a server-side like ASP.NET read client side barcodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barcode readers are usually visible in the system as keyboards so it is enough to have a text field in your application - the user will just scan the code while having focus on this text field.

If you would want to get into more direct contact with the reader, than it would require some *ActiveX* driver for you to be accessible through browser client side code.